# is there a way to run flask on a thread?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, flask

in order to implement a system which exposes REST-api and run another functionality simultaneously, i tried to use flask like the flask like the following:

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.run(threaded=True)
foo()
```

but foo function never starts.

I would to understand how to solve the problem or get an alternative option to implement it.

Thanks!

Comment: What does you foo do?

Answer (score 0):

Going to the documentation for [Flask.run()](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/1.1.x/api/#flask.Flask.run) we see that the options provided (such as threaded) are forwarded to the underlying function `werkzeug.run_simple()`. The [documentation](https://werkzeug.palletsprojects.com/en/0.16.x/serving/#werkzeug.serving.run_simple) for `werkzeug.run_simple()` says the following about the `threaded` parameter:

> threaded – should the process handle each request in a separate thread?

This means that each REST call will be handled in a separate thread, but does not start the server in the background (which seems to be what you want).  Instead, you can use the [`Process`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#the-process-class) class from multiprocessing:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)

from multiprocessing import Process
p = Process(target=app.run)
p.start()
foo()
```

This will start your flask app in the background, letting you run other functions after starting the app.